# Abnormal CPU usage during Disk Write Operations

Tags: linux, centos, performance, centos6, hard-drive

I have a decent CentOS 6.5 dedicated host (CentOS 6.5/E3-1230 3.2Ghz Quad Core + HT/16GB/Software Raid 1 SATA II/[WD2503ABYX](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-701338.pdf)/ext4) with the default CentOS kernel and "elevator=deadline" in grub.

I/O write operations cause a huge spike in CPU usage. Reads are working fine. For example,

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1048576 count=2048
```

causes the host's CPU utilization to shoot above 3 or 4. Under normal operation it remains under 0.40, but when there is some more intense I/O operation everything grinds to a halt.

`mpstat 1` during these `dd` tests shows *io wait* at 20-25%.

Here's the disk layout:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 251.1 GB, 251059544064 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30522 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c6673

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          26      204800   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              26         548     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3             548       30523   240775168   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 251.1 GB, 251059544064 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30522 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00095c99

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1          26      204800   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb2              26         548     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb3             548       30523   240775168   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md2: 246.6 GB, 246552588288 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 60193503 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md1: 4293 MB, 4293910528 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 1048318 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_main-LogVol00: 246.5 GB, 246549577728 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29974 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md0: 209 MB, 209702912 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 51197 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

The problem (high CPU usage) started happening sometime late december last year, which leads me to believe it is software related (the disk susbsystem has been checked by the folks at the DC).

**Which tests should I run next to try to isolate the problem?**

*PS: I'm not looking for performance maximization tips. The server is underutilized. I'm just looking to reduce the CPU load during disk writes.*

**UPDATE: question reworked to better describe the problem.**

**UPDATE: FOUND A SOLUTION** I finally discovered what the problem was when I came across [this post](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/SpecSheet/ENG/2879-701338.pdf).

`root> modprobe vhost_net
root> echo vhost_net > /etc/modules`

For some reason, the virtio interfaces were not loading the driver before. All is good now.

Comment: If these are spinning SATA II disks, then the VM's numbers are right and the host's "1.8GB/s" is wrong by an order of magnitude or so. You should more thoroughly describe your disk subsystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On CentOS, the `dirty_ratio` is set to 20%.

What this means is that writing a file out doing

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1048576 count=2048
```

Actually writes the data into memory as writeback (up to 3.2GB) and does *not* actually write it out to disk.

Its slower (but not a realistic performance benchmark) on the VM because you've probably assigned a much lower memory assignment to the VM itself (lets say 2G) and this leads to `dirty_writeback` only providing ~400MB of writeback before it will force the contents to disk.

If you run that command, then run `sync`, you'll notice sync takes a long time to return.

You need to run your command doing the following instead to get a better idea of your actual throughput.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=test oflag=sync bs=1048576 count=2048
```

Comment: That sounds like exactly what's happening and why he has an unrealistic "1.8GB/s" number.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Yes, now I get 19.3MB/s and 17.1MB/s, which is completely reasonable. The problem is the CPU usage shooting up due to the I/O subsystem being improperly configured. What's the recommended setting and where should I apply it, host/guest/both?

Comment: Please update your question with the IO statistics. You can run `mpstat 5` for the period you run your test and provide the average.

Comment: I will update it and accept this as the answer. The question lost its main point since its based on an improperly executed test.

Comment: Whichever one was giving you the CPU bottleneck. Or both if that was the case. I'm willing to bet its mostly I/O wait though..

Comment: during `dd` with or without sync?

Comment: With sync, unless you're saying now the CPU issue has disappeared using sync?

Comment: it was greatly diminished when using sync